# adding author information for classes in .net

Tags: visual-studio-2010

These days, I have started learning to write enterprise level code and started to follow open source codes. Apart from the readability to have comments in the code, I liked having author name in the code/file which I write.

Do we have any plugin/macro/extension which will automatically add my name and email id in the beginning, to the files which I create in visual studio.

Any plugin or process to generate a template for comments too automatically, automatically cause i can bother less on the template and can bother mmore about the description is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I automate placement of header text (copyright notice, etc) in C# files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441047/how-can-i-automate-placement-of-header-text-copyright-notice-etc-in-c-sharp-f)

Answer (score 1):

> Apart from the readability to have comments in the code, I liked having author name in the code/file which I write.

Why? What *useful* information does it provide, which can't be better ascertained elsewhere? I've always found it a pain, personally - it gets out of date so quickly when other maintainers are involved, and it just clutters up the code.

Any decent source control system will show you the history of a file including who's behind each commit, and also show an annotated version of the file to show which commit last edited each line. Both of these are *far* more useful than hand-written, out-of-date annotations which are irrelevant when actually *writing code*.

I'd strongly advise you to stop even looking for such a feature.

Comment: Thought of having it, atleast till I could afford one source control system. As advised, I would stop looking for such macro, I would rather start searching for a decent source control. Thanks a lot for enlightening me.

Comment: @mi32labs I dare say Git is one of the best SCM's out right now, and it's free.